# awk - extract unique occurrences field 1, append multiple instances of field 2 on the same line in output

Tags: linux, awk

I am working on extracting service objects (ports/protocols) from a large router configuration file. Using awk, I would like to be able to take unique instances of $5 and print them on one line, with the various values in $7 printed after the unique instance of $5 separated by commas.

Input data:

```
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '1'
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '2'
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '3'
set resources group port-group ServiceB port '10'
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '1'
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '2'
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '3'
set resources group port-group ServiceB port '10'
set resources group port-group ServiceB port '20'
set resources group port-group ServiceC port '30'
set resources group port-group ServiceC port '40'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '50'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '5050'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '60'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '65'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '66'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '89'
```

Desired Output:

```
set resources group port-group ServiceA port 1, 2, 3
set resources group port-group ServiceB port 10, 20
set resources group port-group ServiceC port 30, 40
set resources group port-group ServiceD port 50, 5050, 60, 65, 66, 89
```

So far my attempts at making awk statements have not been fruitful.

What I've tried (it's part of a script so that's why there are CR.)

```
awk '{
gsub(/[:\47]/,"")}; i=!seen[$5]++; {print i,$7 } ' inputfile.txt
```

This gives me the following output:

```
set resources group port-group ServiceA port 1
1 1
0 2
0 3
set resources group port-group ServiceB port 8
1 8
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 8
0 3
set resources group port-group ServiceC port 2
1 2
0 3
set resources group port-group ServiceD port 8
1 8
0 5050
0 3
0 83
0 1
0 2
0 990
0 3000
0 3001
0 3002
0 3003
```

I'm assuming I will have to use a multidimensional array with a for loop to accomplish this, but I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: So far I've tried awk ' !seen[$5]++' <various print statements involving $7> <inputfile> but not gaining much traction. Also been using gsub to remove the ' symbols from the output, which seems to be working.

Comment: Update your _exact_ code as part of the question

Comment: Updated post with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '!a[$5]{a[$5]=$0; uniq[$5,$7]=$7}{ if ($5 in a && uniq[$5,$7]!=$7){ 
      a[$5]=a[$5]","$7; uniq[$5,$7]=$7}}END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' inputfile.txt
```

The output:

```
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '1','2','3'
set resources group port-group ServiceB port '10','20'
set resources group port-group ServiceC port '30','40'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '50','5050','60','65','66','89'
```

---

- `!a[$5]{a[$5]=$0; uniq[$5,$7]=$7}` - capturing line at the first occurrence of the unique 5th field value
- `if($5 in a && uniq[$5,$7]!=$7)` - check for duplacate values for the same `Service...`
- `uniq` array if for accumulating unique *bindings* of 5th and 7th fields
- `a[$5]=a[$5]","$7` - add next unique value to the end of the crucial line

---

To get values without single quotes use the following approach:

***group_port_values.awk*** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS="[ ']" }
!a[$5] {
    a[$5] = $0; 
    uniq[$5,$8] = $8
}
{
    if ($5 in a && uniq[$5,$8] != $8) { 
        a[$5] = a[$5]", "$8; 
        uniq[$5,$8] = $8
    }
}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        gsub(/\047/,"",a[i]);
        print a[i]
    }
}
```

***Usage***:

```
awk -f group_port_values.awk inputfile.txt
```

The output:

```
set resources group port-group ServiceA port 1, 2, 3
set resources group port-group ServiceB port 10, 20
set resources group port-group ServiceC port 30, 40
set resources group port-group ServiceD port 50, 5050, 60, 65, 66, 89
```

Comment: @TomA., you're welcome. If you want values without single quotes - use my second approach

Comment: @EdMorton, as for separator, ideally, yes, missed that. That was fixed. You may also review my second approach

Comment: To be honest it's a little hard to read (spreading it out over a few lines with indenting would help) so all I have to suggest is that If you add `{gsub(/\047/,"")}` at the start of the script then you don't need to do it multiple times in the loop. Also note I'm using `/` instead of `"` as the first parameter delimiter as it's a regexp not a string. Actually - since you're including `'` in the FS, do you need the gsub() at all? I'd expect to see one or the other but not both.

Comment: @EdMorton, made my second approach more readable. As for moving `gsub(/\047/,"")` at the start of the script - I doubt about that, cause in that case, it would attempt to substitute each input line. While my approach will substitute only 4 lines instead of 17. How do you think?

Comment: I thought your loop was executing once per port, your code is **much** easier to read now!

Answer (score 2):

TGIF! Here's one for GNU awk using 2D arrays and bad coding habits (:

```
$ awk '
++a[$5 , $7]==1 {                   # if not seen before
    b[$5][++c[$5]]=$7 }             # hash it to b[key][index]
END{ 
    for(i in b) {                   # for all keys
        for(j=1;j<=c[i];j++)        # and all its indexes
            d=(j==1?"":d",")b[i][j] # gather buffer
        sub($5,i)                   # use the last known $0
        sub($NF,d)                  # and replace key and buffer to it
        print }                     # output
}' file
set resources group port-group ServiceA port '1','2','3'
set resources group port-group ServiceB port '10','20'
set resources group port-group ServiceC port '30','40'
set resources group port-group ServiceD port '50','5050','60','65','66','89'
```

Comment: Also useful. It's good to see multiple ways of accomplishing the same task!

Comment: @EdMorton `,` > `FS` > `OFS` check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=", " }
{ gsub(/\047/,""); pfx=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }
$5 != prev { prt(prev); prev=$5 }
!seen[$7]++ { ports[++numPorts] = $7 }
END { prt(prev) }

function prt(sg) {
    if ( sg != "" ) {
        printf "%s %s ", pfx, sg
        for (portNr=1; portNr<=numPorts; portNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", ports[portNr], (portNr<numPorts ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        delete ports
        delete seen
        numPorts = 0
    }
}

$ sort file | awk -f tst.awk
set resources group port-group ServiceA 1, 2, 3
set resources group port-group ServiceB 10, 20
set resources group port-group ServiceC 30, 40
set resources group port-group ServiceD 50, 5050, 60, 65, 66, 89
```

Comment: looks like your output has repeated lines/values and differs from the desired output. Is there any reason?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, I didn't notice the ServiceB in the middle of all the ServiceAs in the input. Thanks for spotting it, corrected now.